# freebsd date conversion failed

Tags: shell, date, freebsd

I try to convert time use shell :

```
date -j -f "%b %e %T %Y %Z" "Aug 5 00:00:00 2011 GMT"
```

but it always failed, why ? my time zone is HKT, Computer os is OSX

here is the error message:
Failed conversion of `Aug 5 00:00:00 2011 GMT'' using format`%b %e %T %Y %Z''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: What current locale are you using? E.g. month name may require translation?

Comment: LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: thx halfbit, I fix it use LC_ALL=en_US date -j -f "%b %e %T %Y %Z" "Aug 5 00:00:00 2011 GMT"

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on FreeBSD;

```
> env TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong date -j -f "%b %e %T %Y %Z" "Aug 5 00:00:00 2011 GMT"
Fri Aug  5 08:00:00 HKT 2011
```

Note that I'm using [tcsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh) here. If you are running ba(sh), you can just use

```
$ TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong date -j -f "%b %e %T %Y %Z" "Aug 5 00:00:00 2011 GMT"
Fri Aug  5 08:00:00 HKT 2011
```

Can you post the failure message, if any?

Comment: ivoryxiong$ TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong date -j -f "%b %e %T %Y %Z" "Aug 5 00:00:00 2011 GMT"
Failed conversion of ``Aug 5 00:00:00 2011 GMT'' using format ``%b %e %T %Y %Z''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]